# scanf("%[^\n]d", x) or scanf("%[0-9]d", x) turns 1 into 49 and 2 into 50

Tags: c, scanf

#### Problem:

I am having problems with `scanf()`. I know from reading forums and the like that `scanf()` is pretty problematic in C, but I'm just still learning the basics, so I don't know all the details.

#### The code snippet that I'd like to solve.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

struct Biodata {
    char name[21],
    address[65],
    date[11],
    phone[17];
};

int main() {
    struct Biodata bio[10];
    int input_max = 0,
    index_struct = 0;
    while (printf("Input the amount of data! ") && scanf("%[0-9]*d", &input_max) < 1) {
        printf("Error! Please, try again!\n\n");
       fflush(stdin);
    }
    for (index_struct = 1; index_struct <= input_max; index_struct++) {
        printf("Your input data count is %d.\n", input_max);
        printf("Data %d.\n", index_struct);
        fflush(stdin);
        while (printf("Name\t: ") && scanf("%[A-Z a-z]s", &bio[index_struct].name) < 1) {
            printf("Error! Please, try again!\n\n");
            fflush(stdin);
        }
        fflush(stdin);
        while (printf("Address\t: ") && scanf("%[^\n]s", &bio[index_struct].address) < 1) {
            printf("Error! Please, try again!\n\n");
            fflush(stdin);
        }
        fflush(stdin);
        while (printf("Birthdate\t: (YYYY/MM/DD)\n") && scanf("%[^\n A-Z a-z]s", &bio[index_struct].date) < 1) {
            printf("Error! Please, try again!\n\n");
            fflush(stdin);
        }
        fflush(stdin);
        while (printf("Phone Number\t: ") && scanf("%[^\n A-Z a-z]s", &bio[index_struct].phone) < 1) {
            printf("Error! Please, try again!\n\n");
            fflush(stdin);
        }
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("Input the index number you'd like the data to be pulled from! ");
    scanf("%d", &index_struct);
    printf("%-10s\n%-64s\n%-10s\n%-16s",
           bio[index_struct].name, bio[index_struct].address,
           bio[index_struct].date, bio[index_struct].phone);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to make every input to be able to output an error, when the input is a whitespace. The scansets of `[^\n]` or `[A-Z]` or `[0-9]` usually helps me in the simpler cases. But, in this one, when I input any number as an input in `input_max` for

```
while (printf("Input the amount of data! ") && scanf("%[0-9]*d", &input_max) < 1) {
    printf("Error! Please, try again!\n\n");
    fflush(stdin);
}
```

The `input_max` gives out different numbers than the ones it was given. What is happening here? What can I do to get around it?

I also don't exactly understand how that snippet of code works as error output as I found that somewhere online.

**EDIT:** as @JonathanLeffler have suggested, the `scanf()` takes my input as code points in either ASCII, ISO 8859-x, or Unicode, or in all of them. But, the input stays as they are when I remove the scanset, turning it into `scanf(%d, &input_max)`. But, I do need the scanset so I can input a whitespace and have the error message I set up to pop up when I input a whitespace in the `scanf()`.

Comment: Your compiler isn't warning you about that? Always compile with `-Wall -Wextra` with GCC or clang, or whatever is done to turn on warnings with other compilers. And read up on `scanf()` formats.

Comment: And `fflush()` is undefined on input streams like `stdin`. See http://c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush.html and http://c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush2.html

Comment: Afif Windy, Who or what text suggest the `s` in `"%[A-Z a-z]s"`?

Comment: No, there's no warning whatsoever. The compiler doesn't detect any error in the code, it just doesn't want to work the way I need it to be.

My compiler is Dev-C++. I found out about fflush() somewhere online and it was written as fflush_stdin(). I tried using that in my codes, but it doesn't work. It somehow works when I write it as fflush(stdin). But, I can't say for sure why or how since I haven't actually fully grasp its concept yet.

Thank you, I will read your recommendations.

Comment: @chux I just thought so, as I need to input a "name" string in the struct. Is there a problem? It works just fine.

Comment: Replace `"%[A-Z a-z]s"` with `"%9[A-Z a-z]"` and review `[`  [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html).

Comment: The digit `1` is ASCII and ISO 8859-x code point 49; the digit `2` is code point 50; etc.  They're also the code points in Unicode, too (`1` maps to U+0031 or 49; `2` maps to U+0032 or 50).  However, the format strings are a mess; it is hard to explain why they're all wrong.

Comment: @chux it works just as fine. Can you explain? I also tried doing the same for %[0-9]d in the first scanf() turning it to scanf(%[0-9], &input_max). It also works fine, but it didn't solve my problem where it turns the input of 1 to 49.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ah, I guess I have suspected that was the case. Also, interestingly, when I remove the scanset and just write it as scanf(%d, &input_max), only then it takes 1 as a 1, and 2 as a 2, and so on. Maybe I'll add this as a note in an edit.

Comment: the scanf input format specifier `%[...]` ALWAYS inputs a string into memory.  The trailing `s` or `d` that the posted code is using, means the next char in `stdin` will be a `s` or a `d`  It has nothing to do with the actual variable.  So that `s` or `d` is an error.  Suggest removing that extraneous character

Comment: @user3629249 Now, I understand the problem. Because of the scanset, my scanf doesn't read my input as integers, but as strings. So, is there no alternative to put out an error with whitespace for integers, then?

Comment: Use `fgets` and check white spaces there except trailing `\n`. If there is no any space use `sscanf` with the format `%i` for integrals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mistaking `[` to be a modifier for `%s` and `%d`—e.g. `%3d`— it is not. `%[` itself is a conversion specifier and works like `%s`.

So, as pointed out in the comment by @user3629249, `s` and `d` at the end of the `%[` specifier (e.g. in `%[^\n A-Z a-z]s`) are extraneous. Also the *spaces* in `%[`  matter.  So `%[A-z a-z]` is different from `%[A-Za-z]`

Let's look at the problems that you get when you compile with format warnings turned on. (-Wformat if you are using gcc or clang) and you will get something like:

```
foo.c:19:68: warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'int *' [-Wformat]
  while (printf("Input the amount of data! ") && scanf("%[0-9]*d", &input_max)<1) {
                                                        ~~~~~      ^~~~~~~~~~
                                                        %d
foo.c:29:55: warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char (*)[21]' [-Wformat]
    while (printf("Name\t: ") && scanf("%[A-Z a-z]s", &bio[index_struct].name)<1) {
                                        ~~~~~~~~~     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
foo.c:34:54: warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char (*)[65]' [-Wformat]
    while (printf("Address\t: ") && scanf("%[^\n]s", &bio[index_struct].address)<1) {
                                           ~~~~      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
foo.c:39:78: warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char (*)[11]' [-Wformat]
    while (printf("Birthdate\t: (YYYY/MM/DD)\n") && scanf("%[^\n A-Z a-z]s", &bio[index_struct].date)<1) {
                                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
foo.c:44:67: warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char (*)[17]' [-Wformat]
    while (printf("Phone Number\t: ") && scanf("%[^\n A-Z a-z]s", &bio[index_struct].phone)<1) {
                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

There are other problems with your code:

1. you indexing your Biodata from 1 to 10 (look at `index_struct` for loop) however it's declared as an array of size 10 `Biodata bio[10];`

In C arrays are `0` based, so they go from `0` to `size-1` and your *for-loop* would run into a segmentation fault because `bio[10]` will be undefined.

2. you are asking for `input_max` *inside* your for-loop but you need it for the for-loop.
3. What happens if input_max is bigger than the declared size of `bio` array?

Some other good things to consider:

4. printf is a bad function to use for reporting errors, errors should go to stderr, not stdout so it's better to use fprintf and specify stderr.
5. since you are interested in ensuring that inputs are parsed correctly why not create your own parser rather than using scanf?
6. you are forcing a re-prompt on error, let's break that up into its own function.

## Let's do it together.

#### Note on the style of C and naming conventions I use below

My C style is a bit different than yours and I have my reasons :-), and since it's just opinion, let's go with mine.

### The struct with some comments on what we want in it

```
struct biodata {
    char name[21];        /* format: FirstName LastName */
    char address[65];     /* format: Free-form upto 65 chars */
    char birthday[11];    /* format: YYYY/MM/DD */
    char phone[17];       /* format: up to digits or a spaces */
};
```

### Some matchers

Below is a set of match functions, that receives an input line and tells us if the line fully matches what we expect. If it does it returns true otherwise it returns false.  You will need to `#include <stdbool.h>` for this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h>

struct biodata {
        char name[21];        /* format: FirstName LastName */
        char address[65];     /* format: Free-form upto 65 chars */
        char birthday[11];    /* format: YYYY/MM/DD */
        char phone[17];       /* format: up to digits or a spaces */
};


bool match_name(const char *line)
{
    char tmp[128];
        return line!=NULL
        && sscanf(line, "%128[A-Za-z]%128[ ]%128[A-Za-z]", tmp, tmp, tmp) == 3
        && strlen(tmp) < 21;
}

bool match_address(const char *line)
{
    return line != NULL
        && strlen(line) > 5
        && strlen(line) < 65; /* no format check here, maybe later */
}

bool match_telephone(const char *line) 
{
    char tmp[128];
    return line  /* notice the alternate form of checking line!=NULL */
        && sscanf(line, "%128[0-9 ]", tmp)==1
        && strlen(tmp) < 17;
}

/* here we'll use strptime to see if our line is a valid date */
bool match_birthday(const char *line) 
{
     struct tm tm; /* time structure */
     if(!line)
          return false;

     return strptime(line, "%Y/%m/%d", &tm) != NULL;
}

char * ask(const char *prompt, char *line, size_t maxlen) 
{
    printf("%-30s:", prompt);
    fflush(stdout);
    fgets(line, maxlen, stdin);
    return line; /* we return the pointer for ease of use */
}

/* a test function */
void test_matchers() {

    char line[256];
    /* remember ask returns our line so we are able to pass it to our matchers */
    while(!match_name(ask("Name (first last)", line, sizeof(line))))
        ;
    while(!match_address(ask("Address (at least 5 chars)", line, sizeof(line))))
        ;
    while(!match_birthday(ask("Birthday (YYYY/MM/DD)", line, sizeof(line))))
        ;
    while(!match_telephone(ask("Telephone (max 16 digits)", line, sizeof(line))))
        ;
}


int main() 
{
     test_matchers();
     return 0;
}
```

Test it out.

```
$ ./bar

Name (first last)             :Ahmed Masud
Address (at least 5 chars)    :1999 Somewhere Out there, Bingo, Bongo, 10002, USA
Birthday (YYYY/MM/DD)         :1970/01/10
Telephone (max 16 digits)     :1-201-555-1212
```

Now let's copy things to our structure in a reasonable way

## Function to print biodata

```
/* add a function to print a biodata */

void print_bio(const struct biodata *bio)
{
    printf("***** bio data *****\n"
       "Name: %-10s\nAddress: %-64s\nBirthday: %-10s\nPhone: %-16s\n",
           bio->name, bio->address,
           bio->birthday, bio->phone);
}
```

## new main function

notice most of it is like `test_matches`. Except we have added the copying of
line to appropriate field

```
int main()
{

    char line[256];
    struct biodata bio;

    while(!match_name(ask("Name (first last)", line, sizeof(line))))
        ;
    strncpy(bio.name, line, sizeof(bio.name));

    while(!match_address(ask("Address (at least 5 chars)", line, sizeof(line))))
        ;
    strncpy(bio.address, line, sizeof(bio.address));

    while(!match_birthday(ask("Birthday (YYYY/MM/DD)", line, sizeof(line))))
        ;
    strncpy(bio.birthday, line, sizeof(bio.birthday));

    while(!match_telephone(ask("Telephone (max 16 digits)", line, sizeof(line))))
        ;
    strncpy(bio.phone, line, sizeof(bio.phone));

    print_bio(&bio);
    return 0;
}
```

Okay so we can prompt the user and get things into our structure but it's clunky to do it in main, so let's make it into its own function.

```
int get_bio(struct biodata *bio)
{

    char line[256];

    while(!match_name(ask("Name (first last)", line, sizeof(line))))
        ;
    strncpy(bio->name, line, sizeof(bio->name));

    while(!match_address(ask("Address (at least 5 chars)", line, sizeof(line))))
        ;
    strncpy(bio->address, line, sizeof(bio->address));

    while(!match_birthday(ask("Birthday (YYYY/MM/DD)", line, sizeof(line))))
        ;
    strncpy(bio->birthday, line, sizeof(bio->birthday));

    while(!match_telephone(ask("Telephone (max 16 digits)", line, sizeof(line))))
        ;
    strncpy(bio->phone, line, sizeof(bio->phone));

    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    struct biodata bio[3]; /* let's get 3 records */
        int i;

        /* bio is made up of a bunch of struct biodata's so we divide its size by sizeof the struct biodata to get how many (in our case 3) */

        for(i = 0; i < sizeof(bio)/sizeof(struct biodata); i++)
        {
            printf("\n\nEnter record number: %d\n", 1+i); /* why 1+i here ? :) */
            get_bio(&bio[i]);
        }

        for(i=0; i < sizeof(bio)/sizeof(struct biodata); i++)
        {
                print_bio(&bio[i]);

        }
    return 0;
}
```

## Exercise

I will leave the rest of the functionality as an exercise.

Meanwhile, I would like you to consider the way we developed this.  Starting from the inner-most functionality and moving slowly outwards.

Break down the problem like bits of lego and work on the inner parts first, test that they do exactly what you want them to do, then slowly build around them.

Obviously, the matchers should have been developed individually and tested before developing ask. I leave it to you to break that down.

Comment: For a baby such as myself, your answer is still a lot to take in, but I'm truly grateful. I understand only some of the points you mentioned. I'll try my best to wrap my head around the rest.

Comment: I'll try to explain a bit more.

Comment: That was such a thorough explanation! Thank you so very much! I'll try my best to study it.

Comment: Please do not advocate the use of `strncpy` to beginners. `strncpy` is a source of bugs and misunderstandings. Write an alternative function that ensures the destination is null terminated.

Comment: `match_telephone` has a bug: `sscanf(line, "%128[0-9 ]", tmp)` should be `sscanf(line, "%127[0-9 ]", tmp)`, same problem in `match_name`

Comment: Also you should have proper checks for end of file. As coded, you have undefined behavior n premature end of file with probable endless loops.